Firebase Function Not Updating Firestore Document with FieldValue.increment Without Error Log
I have a Firebase function triggered on document creation in the "receipts" collection. The function updates the totalReceipts field in a related document in the "projects" collection using FieldValue.increment.
Here’s the relevant code:
const newReceipt = parseInt(data.amount);
    await projectDocRef.update({
      totalReceipts: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(newReceipt),
      updatedUserId: data.userId,
    });

Issue:
In one instance, the totalReceipts field was not updated for a document creation, but no error was logged in the function. Two other updates for the same project worked correctly.
Question:
Is it possible for this Firebase function using FieldValue.increment to fail to update totalReceipts without logging an error? If so, what could be the potential reasons?
I reviewed the Firebase function code to ensure it properly handles the creation of a receipt document and updates the totalReceipts field in the corresponding project document. I checked the Firebase function logs but found no errors, which led me to believe that the update should have been successful.
I expected the totalReceipts field in the Firestore document to increment by the amount specified in the newly created receipt. However, in one instance, the field was not updated, even though there were no errors logged. The function worked correctly for other receipts related to the same project, so I’m unsure why it failed in this particular case without any error message.
Reciepts Collection

Projects Collection


Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your database.

@AlexMamo added screenshot

Have you tried to log the error message if the update operation fails?

Yes, I have included error logging in a try-catch block within the function. I did not see any error logs during the exact time  at which the receipts document was created.

Are you expecting that an increment of a field that doesn't exist in a document to do something specific?  The first document you show doesn't have a totalReceipts field at all, while the second one does.  Please edit the question to explain your expectations more clearly.  Firestore doesn't just fail silently, but it might instead be doing something that you just don't expect.

Please log the values of data, data.amount, and newReceipt, and edit them into your question. I suspect that data.amount is null or undefined and leading to a value of NaN. increment and its underlying class NumericIncrementFieldValueImpl don't use any detailed validation.

@DougStevenson First document is pertaining to "receipts" collection and second document is pertaining to "projects" collection.
On create event of receipts, projects document's 'totalReciepts' value should be incremented.
My query is that if there is any chance that totalReceipts: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(newReceipt) fails due to race condition or any other reason.

@samthecodingman I shall surely include the logs to see the same next time. Here data.amount is not null and it is 26500 (first document)


My query is that if there is any chance that totalReceipts: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(newReceipt) fails due to race condition or any other reason.

No, there is no chance of a failure due to a race condition.  The increment should always happen in all circumstances, barring some exceptional case, such as the violation of a security rule or some other permission error, or maybe even integer overflow.  If there is a failure, your error handling code will pick that up if written correctly.  Firestore will not fail silently in any case.
